Bitcoin core functional tests failing running on WSL2 on Windows 10
I am running this command (using a 4GB temp HD mounted):
# test/functional/test_runner.py --cachedir=/mnt/tmp/cache --tmpdir=/mnt/tmp

And for all tests I get this errors:
feature_fee_estimation.py                  | ✖ Failed  | 38 s
mempool_accept.py                          | ✖ Failed  | 6 s
mempool_limit.py                           | ✖ Failed  | 0 s
mempool_package_limits.py                  | ✖ Failed  | 1 s
mempool_sigoplimit.py                      | ✖ Failed  | 3 s
p2p_addr_relay.py                          | ✖ Failed  | 12 s
p2p_blocksonly.py                          | ✖ Failed  | 0 s
p2p_compactblocks_blocksonly.py            | ✖ Failed  | 0 s
p2p_feefilter.py                           | ✖ Failed  | 9 s
p2p_segwit.py                              | ✖ Failed  | 26 s
p2p_sendtxrcncl.py                         | ✖ Failed  | 3 s
wallet_fundrawtransaction.py --descriptors | ✖ Failed  | 10 s
wallet_miniscript.py --descriptors         | ✖ Failed  | 8 s
wallet_sendall.py --descriptors            | ✖ Failed  | 6 s

Then I got this first file to test:

feature_fee_estimation

And only for it I got this error:
2024-09-16T02:26:26.749000Z TestFramework (ERROR): Unexpected exception caught during testing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/bitcoin-core/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 131, in main 
    self.run_test()
  File "/root/bitcoin-core/test/functional/feature_fee_estimation.py", line 434, in run_test
    self.restart_node(0, ["-blocksonly"])
  File "/root/bitcoin-core/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 583, in restart_node
    self.start_node(i, extra_args)
  File "/root/bitcoin-core/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 541, in start_node
    node.wait_for_rpc_connection()
  File "/root/bitcoin-core/test/functional/test_framework/test_node.py", line 257, in wait_for_rpc_connection
    raise FailedToStartError(self._node_msg(
test_framework.test_node.FailedToStartError: [node 0] bitcoind exited with status 1 during initialization. Error: -maxmempool must be at least 9 MB
************************

2024-09-16T02:26:26.800000Z TestFramework (INFO): Stopping nodes
[node 2] Cleaning up leftover process
[node 1] Cleaning up leftover process
[node 0] Cleaning up leftover process

stderr:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/bitcoin-core/test/functional/feature_fee_estimation.py", line 441, in <module>
    EstimateFeeTest().main()
  File "/root/bitcoin-core/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 154, in main
    exit_code = self.shutdown()
  File "/root/bitcoin-core/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 313, in shutdown
    self.stop_nodes()
  File "/root/bitcoin-core/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 574, in stop_nodes
    node.stop_node(wait=wait, wait_until_stopped=False)
  File "/root/bitcoin-core/test/functional/test_framework/test_node.py", line 377, in stop_node
    self.stop(wait=wait)
  File "/root/bitcoin-core/test/functional/test_framework/test_node.py", line 207, in __getattr__
    assert self.rpc_connected and self.rpc is not None, self._node_msg("Error: no RPC connection")
AssertionError: [node 0] Error: no RPC connection

I also changed my /etc/resolve.conf to this, but no success:
search localtest.me
options ndots:15
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

What else can I try to make all tests work? Thanks

"Error: -maxmempool must be at least 9 MB" ⇒ did you limit the mempool or do you think that this was an RPC failure?

I think is a RPC failure, all the other tests are working. Where can I see this maxmempool parameter?

I don't know why, but running command solved the problem:
make distclean
And then running all again

Sometimes when you have previously built from source and then pull updates to the repository, it doesn’t correctly detect all the parts that need to be rebuilt. In that case, it can help to fully reset the build and start over. It seems that this was the case here and that’s why make distclean resolved your issue.
